# How to implement an async timer in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm implementing an audio recorder in Xamarin.Forms. There should be a timer displaying the time the recorder is running. On tapping on a image, the recording starts, and if the user taps again, the recording stops. The tapped command code looks like:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     The on tabbed command.
    /// </summary>
    private async void OnTappedCommand()
    {
        if (this.isRecording)
        {
            this.isRecording = false;
            await this.StopRecording().ConfigureAwait(false); // Stops the MediaRecorder
        }
        else
        {
            this.isRecording = true;
            await this.StartTimer().ConfigureAwait(false); // Starts the Timer
            await this.StartRecording().ConfigureAwait(false); // Starts the MediaRecorder
        }
    }
```

The StartTimer() method looks like:

```
private async Task StartTimer()
    {
        Device.StartTimer(
            new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
            () =>
                {
                    if (this.isRecording)
                    {
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
                            () =>
                                {
                                    this.TimerValue = this.TimerValue + 1;
                                });

                        return true;
                    }

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
                        () =>
                            {
                                this.TimerValue = 0;
                            });

                    return false;
                });
}
```

The *TimerValue* is a simple integer property bound to a label that's using a ValueConverter to handle the formatting.

My Questions are:

**1. Why does my code work even if I remove the Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread method? Shouldn't it throw an error because it's not running on the UI-Thread and trying to update the UI-Bound TimerValue Property, since ConfigureAwait(false) is used?**

**2. Where do you suggest to use Task.Run() in this code, or should'nt it be used at all?**

Comment: 1) The compiler is giving you a warning that `StartTimer` runs synchronously; don't ignore it. 2) What does `Device.StartTimer` do?

Comment: I would recommend to count the recording time with a System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch because your method will result in a wrong TimerValue.

Answer (score 0):

1 - It works because the timer will run the code in the **UI Thread** (Main Thread).
The same used by Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread().
*You can use it when your code is running out of the **UI Thread** (see the next answer)*

2 - Should'nt it be used at all in your example because this.TimerValue was created by (and is property of) the **UI Thread**
Task.Run() execute the code in a "thread pool" and cannot touch the objects created by the "UI Thread".
The "Thread Pool" is to be used for long jobs and that should not interact with the UI.